# Is there a hotkey to make selected text quoted?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have some items that were variable names that should actually be strings, is there a quick way to quote them once I select them, or do I need to manually type in the quotes on each side of the string?

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight a word, pressing a quote key such as " will quote the word, instead of replacing the word with a quote.